# How to serialize an object as JSON?

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

I have an object that's pretty extensive (lots of properties and child relationships).  I'd like to serialize it.  So I am doing the following:

```
Proposal__c proposal = (Proposal__c) getRecord();
String s = JSON.serialize(proposal);
```

The output:

```
{"attributes":      
    {
       "type":"WWK_Proposal__c",
       "url":"/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/WWK_Proposal__c/a0cM0000001BfBLIA0"
    },
    "Id":"a0cM0000001BfBLIA0"
}
```

And that is all.  How can I get the entire object serialized, perhaps even including its child relationships?

Comment: Does the object returned by getRecord() populate more fields, or just those three?

Answer (score 12):

You probably need to query more fields to expose them in your serialization. It would help if you posted your `getRecord()` code, but the following ought to work:

```
SObject getRecord()
{
    List<String> fieldsToQuery = Proposal__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values();
    String fields = String.join(fieldsToQuery, ', ');
    String soqlQuery = String.format('SELECT {0} FROM Proposal__c LIMIT 1', new List<String> { fields });
    return Database.query(soqlQuery)
}

Proposal__c proposal = (Proposal__c) getRecord();
String s = JSON.serialize(proposal);
```

Comment: Just add the new `Security.stripInaccessible(AccessType.READABLE, new List<Proposal__c>{proposal}).getRecords()[0];` to only return the record with readable fields.  Reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_stripInaccessible.htm)